# Is it possible to retrieve the ReducedRecipient.RecipientTypeDetails property as an integer value using Powershell?

Tags: c#, powershell

I am using Powershell to make a call to Get-Recipient which returns the ReducedRecipient object. The power shell command is run using C# code and the returned object is processed within C#.

However, I want to retrieve only the RecipientTypeDetails property from this object as an integer value using Powershell (to be later processed in C# code).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm following you...

```
$recipient.RecipientTypeDetails.Value__
```

Comment: I am currently running the powershell command Get-Recipient -Identity 7X3207CQEG.  Where do I use $recipient.RecipientTypeDetails.Value__ within this?  Thanks

Comment: (Get-Recipient -Identity 7X3207CQEG).RecipientTypeDetails.Value__